# SQL query not showing any results (closed)

Tags: php, sql

I'm making now activation page for my website. I'm running there SQL query which looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE token = '545f9390-fc09-11e9-abd0-9822efb9cbff'`

But when I run it, it shows no results. Token of course exists in database. I tried running this query in phpmyadmin but is hasn't worked either. How can i modify this query to get matching result. In query i tried `LIKE` insted of `=` but it hasn't worked.

My php code:

```
<?php

    include "dbConnection/dbconn.php";
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
    use Ramsey\Uuid\Exception\UnsatisfiedDependencyException;


    if (!empty($_GET['token'])) {
        $token = $_GET['token'];
        $isValid = Uuid::isValid($token);
        if(!$isValid) {
            echo "Invalid token!";
            die();
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `token` = '$token'"; 
        echo $sql;
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $result = $result->fetch();
        print_r($result);
    } else {
        echo "Account cannot be activated.";
        echo "Sorry for inconvenience.";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Can you show the row in your database?

Comment: And can you confirm your users table is `Users` and not `users` (lower case)?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/A0rG1hl

Comment: It is Users (upper case)

Comment: It looks like it should work. Try `WHERE token LIKE '%$token%'` to see if maybe there is a space or invisible character in the database causing it to not match.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) attack. 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Ok, if that works with the wildcards, that means your database has an invisible character in the field -- more than likely a space. Make sure whatever writes to the db does a `trim()` on the value first.

Comment: @RiggsFolly how can i do this? I have changed my statement execution to this: https://pastebin.com/HhrtjTYJ . But is is not working

Comment: [Have a read on this page](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#like)

Comment: i have done it but now how to display it? I have done it in foreach loop but not working

Comment: @KamilWaniczek  try to use this code directly and see anything working?? if yes then change dbconn.php code like what i have given. don't forget to change database credentials in the given code: https://3v4l.org/XYn6E

Comment: Ok i got this working. Thanks everyone for helping me :)